# Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined When installing Jest in Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-jest

I want to use `jset` in my angular project. when I run the following command:

```
npm install jest --save-dev
```

Get the following error :

> npm ERR! Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined

NOTE:
before install `jest` I remove completely `Karam` with the following command :

```
npm remove karma karma-chrome-launcher karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter karma-jasmine karma-jasmine-html-reporter
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

it might help some one.
I solved it by few workarounds by reinstalling below packages:

1. removed node_modules and package-lock.json file
2. npm install -g npm@latest
3. when run npm install I got bug at node-gyp. i have to run npm i -g node-gyp

Now its working fine for me.